# Getting `<option>` value from `<select>` using JavaScript only works in debug mode

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on this project where I need to get the selected value from the user and and do a simple if - else. However, I'm not being able to get the value of the selected option from the user.

```html
<select id = "insulinStrength" name="insulinStrength" type="text" class="selectBtn" >
    <option value="">Select Insulin Type</option>
    <option value="Novolog">Novolog</option>
    <option value="Humalog">Humalog</option>
    <option value="Apidra">Apidra</option>
    <option value="Velosulin">Velosulin</option>
</select>
```

```
function getInsulinStrength() {
    let insulinSt = document.getElementById('insulinStrength'),
    selectedNode = insulinSt.options[insulinSt.selectedIndex];

    if (selectedNode.value ==="Humalog"){
        insulinStrengthTotal = 1800;
    } else {
        insulinStrengthTotal = 1500;
    }

    return insulinStrengthTotal;
}
```

This value needs to be put in the function below:

```
function doTheMath(){

    let carbIntake = getCurrentMeal();
    let cbs = getCurrentBloodSugar();
    let tbs = getTargetBloodSugar();
    let br = getBasalRate();
    let is = getInsulinStrength();

    let dailyBasalRate = br * 24;
    let gramsPerInsulin = 450 / dailyBasalRate;
    let bolus = carbIntake / gramsPerInsulin;

    if (cbs > tbs) {
        let correctionFactor = is / dailyBasalRate;
        let correctionDose = (cbs - tbs) / correctionFactor;
        bolus += correctionDose;
    }

    return bolus;
}
```

Everything else works minus the `getInsulinStrength()` function. Regardless of what the user chooses, it returns the same value.

The result is supposed to change when the user chooses Humalog. But the *results always stay the same for every single selected value*.

**IT HAS CORRECT FUNCTIONALITY ONLY IN DEBUG MODE, HOWEVER IN REGULAR BROWSER MODE IT DOESN'T.**

Comment: let  insulinStrengthTotal = 0;

is a value before the snippet of code.

Comment: If you've found other questions which are the same as yours, add commentary about what you didn't understand about them so that we can help. Stack Overflow is here to help you **and everyone else with the same question**; the latter being more important than the former.

Comment: @HereticMonkey got you. I will do that next time.

Comment: @MohitPaudyal please do it _this time_, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55670711/edit)

Comment: _" the value selected cannot be in the HTML tag"_ <- can you explain what this means? What value do you expect to get from the `<select>`? Also, what triggers `doTheMath` to execute?

Comment: I tried that as well. Doesn't work. ~ I tried both ( .value and .text) . I don't see why its not getting the value

Comment: @Phil It goes like this. A user can select an option get a result, select another option get result. doTheMath is executed by the button below the select tag. I can get the result ~ getting the result is working. However, there is one type of insulin that needs different values ( 1800 ) and that would change the result. But that result is not changing.

Comment: I tried to [reproduce your issue on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpxk0fzn/) but it works as expected. I'd suggest checking in your browser's console for errors. The only other explanation is that your HTML does not actually contain `<option value="Humalog">Humalog</option>`. Double-check the `value` in the HTML source code

Comment: Thank you. there is no issues even in the console. If I find what I am doing wrong I'll post here. Thank you guys.

Comment: Just curious have you tried to change this `if (selectedNode.value ==="Humalog"){` to this `if (selectedNode.value == "Humalog"){`.  I know that seems silly but what've got to lose.

Comment: @Cooper yup did that as well. I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: The only thing I changed was `let` to `var` because I built it in Google Apps Script Editor.  I'll try posting the code minified in the next comment if I can fit it.

Comment: Oh I also removed the type and the class.

Comment: The code that you shared with us runs as is on JSFiddle.

Comment: Please [edit] your questions with code that, when run, reproduces the situation. Take the code in your real project, remove code until it starts working, add code back until it stops working, and only then, post the code. This is called creating a [mcve] and is explained at that link and on [ask].

Comment: @MohitPaudyal i have an answer for your recently deleted question

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your code works or when you execute that function, but here you have a snippet that alerts when you select an option form the select.

https://jsfiddle.net/MSclavi/m641xba9/5/

Adding `onchange` to the `select` works like a charm

```
<select id = "insulinStrength" onchange="getInsulinStrength()" name="insulinStrength" class="selectBtn" >
    <option value="">Select Insulin Type</option>
    <option value="Novolog">Novolog</option>
    <option value="Humalog">Humalog</option>
    <option value="Apidra">Apidra</option>
    <option value="Velosulin">Velosulin</option>
</select>
```

Maybe you can merge that with your code, but in following questions, please provide a fiddle or a working code. Cheers!

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) rather than jsFiddles. They keep the code here on Stack Overflow so that people don't have to go to another site to run the code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey will do. Thanks!

Comment: @MSclavi I like your idea, but unfortunately that is the part that works. Let me see if I can add a fiddle. Maybe that will give even more insight

Comment: So when you execute doTheMath, it doesn't use the value you want?

Comment: @MSclavi yes, it doesn't use the specific insulin strength ~ 1800 for Humalog, rather uses generic value ~ 1500 or something else.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/MSclavi/m641xba9/10/. When you click the button, it shows you the right amount. If it helps you, I'll edit this answer to use the snippets here

Comment: @MohitPaudyal did it help?

Comment: @MSclavi I get the results right. See the insulin strength differs per use case. ( if a user chooses a different insulin gets a different result). But the math always returns the same. And the same code is on my back end server ( which works spotless - in java).. Don't knw what is going on. ugh

Comment: @MohitPaudyal there is a case where insulin strength isn't used, when `(cbs > tbs)` is false

Comment: @MSclavi yes. there is.. You know what is amazing, in browser debug mode its working. in regular browser mode its not

Comment: @MohitPaudyal weird... I created an html file with the contents of the fiddle and open it on chrome and mozilla, and both times work as intended. I used your doTheMath method with some numeric values to make use of the insuln value